# php, fill array and read its items using a loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am beginner to PHP array. Please give  example where I fill array by assigning separate values. After filling the array, I want to read its items using a loop.

Filling simply like following:

```
$WrongQ[1] = "1";
$WrongQ[2] = "2";
```

Reading simply like following ( something like in C language)

```
$i=1;
        while($WrongQ)
        {
            echo $WrongQ[$i].",";

            $i=$i+1;
        }
```

I got lost when I started reading about PHP array. Please make things easy for me.
Thanks

Comment: try changing `while($WrongQ)` to `while($i<=count($WrongQ))`. And you can simplify `$i=$i+1;` to just `$i++;`

Comment: what is $WrongQ? Is it a sql variable?

Comment: C also has `for` and all its children have `foreach`, so use one of those obviously.

Comment: `foreach(range(1,2) as $value) echo $value.",";`, your welcome ;p

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php and click on the "foreach" section in the "see also" below it so see a way to loop through the array. That's all the array functions that should help you populate the array and then spit out the data after. `array_push()` should help you to populate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note in PHP, arrays are normally 0 indexed, but also arrays are not a regular array primitive like in other languages (they are actually an ordered map), so they also can have any string or integer as an index.  I'm simplying by using the implode function, which will concatenate the strings in your array, separated by a separator you define.

```
$foo = array();

for($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++)
{
   $foo[$i] = $i;
}

echo implode(',', $foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how arrays work in PHP, nor is it how while loops work. You want something like this:

```
$WrongQ = array();
// assign some values
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    $WrongQ[$i] = "Question " . $i;
}
// do something with them
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    echo $WrongQ[$i] . "<br/>";
}
```

Output:

```
Question 1
Question 2
Question 3
Question 4
Question 5
```

You can also use `foreach($WrongQ)` to loop over the values *after* you have set them.

Answer (score 0):

first of all Index Array start with 0

use For or foreach loop to get data like this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp)

```
foreach ($WrongQ as $value) {
  echo "$value <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP arrays start at zero so try this:

```
$WrongQ = array();

$WrongQ[0] = "1";
$WrongQ[1] = "2";

for ($i=0; $i<count($WrongQ); $i++)
{
    echo $WrongQ[$i];
}
```

One of my favorite ways to add things to arrays is incrementally like so (starts at zero and adds one per element without having to do the numbers).

```
PHP arrays start at zero so try this:

$WrongQ = array();

$WrongQ[] = "1";
$WrongQ[] = "2";

for ($i=0; $i<count($WrongQ); $i++;)
{
    echo $WrongQ[$i];
}
```